# jquery tabs - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery

Html code is:

```
<div id="questions">
  <ul>
       <li class="selected"><a href="#fly">Fly</a></li>
       <li><a href="#fly1">Fly 1</a></li>
  </ul>

 <div id="fly" style="display: block;">   
   <div id="question141">
   <div id="question104">
   <div id="question80">
   <div id="question79">
 </div>
 <div id="fly1">
   <div id="question141">
   <div id="question104">
   <div id="question80" >
   <div id="question79" >
 </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#questions  div').hide();
    jQuery('#questions  div:first').show();
    jQuery('#questions  ul li:first').addClass('active');

    jQuery('#questions  ul li a').click(function(){
        jQuery('#questions  ul li').removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass('active');
        var currentTab = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery('#questions  div').hide();
        jQuery(currentTab).show();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Above code has two tabs and i am using jQuery to show tabs on click. But when i click any tab. The  elements inside the tab does not show. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Why not use jqueryui instead? http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: i tried. it makes things too complex for me. not understanding that how to use.

Comment: Its a lot easier to use then trying to build it yourself. $( "#questions" ).tabs(); and it's done. your html is similar to what it needs to create tabs by default. If you got to the page i showed you, look at the source code, by clicking view source for an example.

Comment: I looked at what you sent me @Matt . One question though i need to download jquery.ui.tabs.js for it to work? As it is giving me error when i try that function that tabs() does not exist?

Comment: yes, jqueryui and jquery are different. Best thing to do is include it from google. https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js, http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html, you will also need to style it. You need the css from jqueryui as well. You can create your own style, or use one of the default ones.

Comment: @Matt thanks a lot buddy... It worked and is much easier... Thanks again...

Comment: @Matt let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1717/discussion-between-gurnor-and-matt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say jQuery('#questions div').hide() or show() it will hide all divs inside #questions div. Please try below code it will work for you.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#questions > div').hide();
    jQuery('#questions  div:first').show();
    jQuery('#questions  ul li:first').addClass('active');

    jQuery('#questions  ul li a').click(function(){
        jQuery('#questions  ul li').removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass('active');
        var currentTab = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery('#questions > div').hide();
        jQuery(currentTab).show();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Gurnor - Please use this it will definately work for you if you dont want to use jquery ui tabs.

Answer (score 1):

All those question divs are unclosed.. close them and then your code works

Your code works for me... Why do you think it doesnt? Here is a jsfiddle where you can see. When you click on a link the different tabs appear.

use this HTML to see that it works with your current javascript

```
<div id="questions">
  <ul>
       <li class="selected"><a href="#fly">Fly</a></li>
       <li><a href="#fly1">Fly 1</a></li>
  </ul>

 <div id="fly" style="display: block;">   
 fly........
 </div>
 <div id="fly1">
   fly1
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your markup will work because there are no nested divs with fly/fly1 div. When we say $("questions div").hide(), it will hide all the divs even the nested divs thats why nothing is visible. We should say hide the immediate children using  $("questions > div").hide()

Answer (score 1):

You are doing many *things* wrong.

Demo on jQuery UI Tabs: http://jsfiddle.net/Qj23q/